# Does AWS Lambda duplicate every message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CodePipeline build running in AWS, and everything works great, except there's no good notification mechanism directly from within CodePipeline.  Digging around, it seems that the accepted solution for this is to configure CloudWatch to call Lambda or SNS to send off your message.

OK, so I built a small Java program to send a message to Slack based on CloudWatch CodePipeline events.  It works well, except that *every single message* is repeated a half dozen times or more.  This seems different from all the other posts I've read around duplicated Lambda executions where you get an occasional duplicate here or there.

I know the standard answer is that Lambda wants to ensure delivery, so events may be retried, which is fine - if every 20 or 100 messages I got a duplicate, I'd be fine.  But I can't flood a Slack channel with 50+ messages for every simple CP run.  Not to mention I assume I'm getting billed for every one of those Lambda executions, when really I should only be getting 4 per run.

I don't want to have to set up a DB to track unique IDs - again that's adding both complexity and cost (the executions still happen).  It feels like something is mis-configured.  E.g. Is there a reason CloudWatch would be picking up the same message and forwarding it to Lambda for some reason?  Or a reason that Lambda would think the execution needs to be retried even though it exits successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this depends on how you have configured your CloudWatch event listener. If not careful, you will trigger actions on CodePipeline stage transitions or Action rather than CodePipeline state changes. Copied from the  [Detect and React to Changes in Pipeline State with Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html) chapter in the CodePipeline user guide:

You can configure notifications to be sent when the state changes for:

> - Specified pipelines or all your pipelines. You control this by using
>     "detail-type": "CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change".
> - Specified stages or all your stages, within a specified pipeline or all your pipelines. You control this by using "detail-type": "CodePipeline Stage Execution State Change".
> - Specified actions or all actions, within a specified stage or all stages, within a specified pipeline or all your pipelines. You control this by using "detail-type": "CodePipeline Action Execution State Change".

For example, if you are only interested in when the CodePipeline is completed, you would configure CloudWatch Events as:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.codepipeline"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change",
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [ 
      "SUCCEEDED", 
      "FAILED", 
      "CANCELED"
    ],
    "pipeline": [{ "Ref": "myPipeline" }]
  }
}
```

Comments:

- Note that `STARTED`, `RESUMED` and `SUPERSEDED` was omitted from the state list above (which may or may not be what you like)
- Be aware that *Execution State Change* has different states compared to *Stage Execution State Change* which in turn differs from *Action Execution State Change*.
- Leave out the `pipeline` part of the configuration to listen to events from all CodePipelines that you have as opposed to specific one(s).
- Read more in the CodePipeline [user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html) mentioned earlier.

Comment: YES!  I was going nuts trying to find this, thank you!